# SQL Table Function Parser

Tags: sql-server, parsing, extract

So I'm looking for a tool or method to allow me to rework a SQL table function, so that I can trace the output columns backwards and determine their origin, and/or produce one liners of SQL that make up the content of each column.

Actually, the end goal is to convert all of this logic to JavaScript where I can plug in an extracted and matching data object (representative of the actual SQL table) as the data source. So if anyone knows of a good way to approach this, then I'd love to hear about it. But I figured a good place to start was some sort of language parser for SQL.

I came across [GSP](http://www.sqlparser.com/sql-parser-dotnet.php) but I'm not sure if it will be able to do this type of job. Looking for some advice or ideas.

P.S. I'd do this manually if I only needed to convert a handful of functions, but I need to this for probably about 250 that have varying levels of implementations.

Comment: probably the best you can do is use the "find dependencies" button in the management studio. This should tell you all of the places taht reference the function, then use that list and trace the dependencies all the way back. There is probably a way to automate tracing back from the dependency data that already exists in sql server.

Comment: Good idea! That's definitely a piece of the puzzle, of course the more complicated piece is to automate how each return column relies on those dependencies.

Comment: i doubt you will be able to get to that level of automation. The system as far as I know will get you the procedure or function that called the function, but not a column by column basis.

Comment: True, I'm not expecting for this to be 100% automated. More so looking for tools/methods that are gonna make this as painless as possible, then I'll throw a layer of custom logic over on top of it for my specific needs.